# Django pagination and "current page"

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm currently developing a Django application which will make use of the infamous "pagination" technique.  I'm trying to figure out how the django.core.paginator module works.

I have an application with a Question model.  I will be listing all of the questions using this paginator.  There will be 20 questions per page.

```
def show_question(question_pk):
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(questions, 20)
    page      = ... # Somehow figure out which page the question is on
    return render_to_response('show_question.html', { 'page' : page })
```

In the view, where I list the different pages as "... 2, 3, **4**, 5, 6, ..." I want to highlight the current page somehow, like many pages do.

There are really two things I want to know:

1. How do I make Django figure out which page the question is located at?
2. How would I write my template to properly "highlight" the currently visited page?

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot part of this question.  I would also like any page except for the current one to be a link to `/questions/{{ that_page.start_index }}`.  So basically every page link would link to the first question on that page.

Comment: What do you mean you want every page except the current to link to the question on that page? How will the user ever change pages?

Comment: I don't want to pass any ?page=4 GET request parameter or anything.  I will only use /question/4 for question 4, and then the view will figure out which page that question is on.  This is why the page links are really directed to questions.

Comment: Wouldn't the first question on a page change as more questions are added, or possibly sorted? From a REST/HTTP perspective, this means that the URL does not refer to a real resource. This is why Django uses a GET parameter: to annotate the display characteristics of the resource the URL identifies.

Comment: While that is true, this particular application will only be used to view predefined questions.  The questions will never change.

Comment: The current page is called `page_obj`.
To see what to do with it look <a href="https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/03/how-to-paginate-with-django.html">here</a>.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hmm... I see from your comment that you don't want to do the ol' GET parameter, which is what django.core.paginator was written for using.  To do what you want, I can think of no better way than to precompute the page that each question is on.  As an example, your view will end up being something like:

```
ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 20
def show_question(question_pk):
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    for index, question in enumerate(questions):
        question.page = ((index - 1) / ITEMS_PER_PAGE) + 1
    paginator = Paginator(questions, ITEMS_PER_PAGE)
    page = paginator.page(questions.get(pk=question_pk).page)
    return render_to_response('show_question.html', { 'page' : page })
```

To highlight the current page in the template, you'd do something like

```
{% for i in page.paginator.page_range %}
    {% ifequal i page.number %}
        <!-- Do something special for this page -->
    {% else %}
        <!-- All the other pages -->
    {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

As for the items, you'll have two different object_lists to work with...

```
page.object_list
```

will be the objects in the current page and

```
page.paginator.object_list
```

will be all objects, regardless of page.  Each of those items will have a "page" variable that will tell you which page they're on.

That all said, what you're doing sounds unconventional.  You may want to rethink, but either way, good luck.

Comment: Oh boy, oh boy!  `page.paginator.object_list[i].page` sounds like it's probably exactly what I was looking for!  I'll check that out immediately.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Django, [at least](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/pagination/) from version 1.2, allows us to complete this task by using pure default pagination template tags.

```
{% for page in article_list.paginator.page_range %}
  {% if page == article_list.number %}
    {{ page }}
  {% else %}
    <a href="/page{{ page }}">{{ page }}</a>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Where article_list is instance of

```
paginator = Paginator(article_list, 20)
    try:
        article_list = paginator.page(int(page))
    except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        article_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

Comment: +1 wonderful... is it possible to write stackoverflow like pagination(ie: `prev 1 ... 7 8 9 10 11 ... 500435 next`). i mean the `...`

Comment: @suhail, yes it is possible to do it, just modify the template using [django template syntax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/). But I would rather recommend you to try [django-endless-pagination](http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) app. It is simple to set up and has sane defaults for all sorts of pagination styles.

Answer (score 5):

[django-pagination](http://eflorenzano.com/blog/post/first-two-django-screencasts/#using-django-pagination) should do what you want and comes wrapped in a pretty package you can just plug-in and use. It essentially moves the code from your views to the templates and a middleware.

EDIT: I just saw your edit.
You can get the current objects on a page using `{% autopaginate object_list %}`, which replaces `object_list` with the current objects for any given page. You can iterate through it and if you want the first, you should be able to treat it like a list and do `object_list[0]`.

If you want to keep this within your views, you could do something like this:

```
def show_question(question_pk):
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(questions, 20)
    return render_to_response('show_question.html', { 'page' : paginator })
```

Within your template, you can access the current page you're on by doing:

```
# Gives you the starting index for that page.
# For example, 5 objects, and you're on the second page. 
# start_index will be 3.
page.start_index

# You can access the current page number with:
# 1-based index
page.number
```

With that, you should be able to do everything you need.
There are a couple good examples [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/).

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  However, to me it seems that django-pagination does nothing more than the built-in pagination stuff, but simply moves the logic from the code into the templates and a middleware.  Is it so?

Comment: Essentially, yes. I updated my answer if you want to keep your pagination login inside your view.