# django pagination: How to get number of page by id of element in the list

Tags: django

I use [django-paginaton](http://code.google.com/p/django-pagination/) app and I'm very glad to use it. Now I need feature, that I don't know how to implement. I have list of elements, that paginated by django's paginator. I have one element with specified id, that I should show, but I don't know what page contains it. I need mechanism jump to the page, that contains my element.

I think it's a good idea if django-pagination will support this transparently and automatically. For example, I set special context variable `page_by_id` to X and if `page` is None, it will be defined to the value, that contains my X element.

What do you think about this mechanism?
May be there is another clean way to do this?

This is for continue of this questions:

- [Django pagination and "current page"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747648/django-pagination-and-current-page)
- [Django Pagination - Redirecting to the page an object is on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858316/django-pagination-redirecting-to-the-page-an-object-is-on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least, I wrote [patch](http://code.google.com/p/django-pagination/issues/detail?id=60) for **django-pagination** that provide 2 features:

1. Get number of page by id of element inside paginated list;
2. Possibility to rename default parameter 'page' to another value for
   using it inside template;

This works transparently by adding 2
optional parameters in autopaginate templatetag:

```
{% autopaginate object_list paginated_by orphans page_by_id parameter_name %}
```